# Process data of large files from nodejs to insert them in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, shopify-app

I'm looking for the most efficient way under nodejs to process large jsonl files (coming from an url like https://storage.googleapis.com/shopify../file.jsonl) and then insert them in mongodb according to my schema.

Example of jsonl file :

```
{productId = « p1 », productTitle = « Tee-shirt »}
{variantId = « v1 », variantTitle = « S », productId = « p1 »}
{variantId = « v2 », variantTitle = « M », productId = « p1 »}
{productId = « p2 », productTitle = « Car »}
{variantId = « v3 », variantTitle = « Blue », productId = « p2 »}
{variantId = « v4 », variantTitle = « Black », productId = « p2 »}
{variantId = « v5 », variantTitle = « L », productId = « p1 »}
```

I manage this with streams using the JSONStream and event-stream packages.

In the end, I have to insert this in mongodb with this example :

```
{
    productId = « p1 », 
    productTitle = « Tee-shirt », 
    variants : [
        {variantId = « v1 », variantTitle = « S »},
        {variantId = « v2 », variantTitle = « M »},
        {variantId = « v5 », variantTitle = « L »}
    ]},
{
    productId = « p2 », 
    productTitle = « Car »,
    variants : [
        {variantId = « v3 », variantTitle = « Blue »}
        {variantId = « v4 », variantTitle = « Black »}
    ]},
}
```

Knowing that the jsonl file will contain a large number of lines, what is the best solution between :

1. Do I have to initialize an array in memory and add the lines of the stream one after the other, and make a single bulk insertion in mongodb with this final big array ? if yes, won't it saturate the memory ?
2. Do I have to do an update in mongodb for each recovered stream ? so in this case there will be a lot of insert requests, so will the cost of many insert requests to mongodb be too expensive ?
3. Or another solution maybe ?

Thank you in advance for your help.